# Init listening to buttons of a BT headset

Tags: c#, windows, button, bluetooth, headset

I want my c# program to react on button press of a Bluetooth headset, but I'm stuck trying to connect.

I use InTheHand.Net.Sockets and I can find the wanted device. So I think, the following lines are clear:

```
BluetoothClient BTC = ...
BluetoothDeviceInfo HSI = Devices[aName];
InTheHand.Net.BluetoothAddress btAdress = HSI.DeviceAddress;
```

After this I should call

```
BTC.BeginConnect(btAdress, ???
```

But I don't know which value I have to use for Guid service in order to be able to query the buttons later.

Comment: Enumerate services on your device. Then, depending os supported services, you can connect to one of them. After connection established (if that supports HFP, you can not connect to AVRCP and/or A2DP) you have to execute some initialization sequence on the HFP control channel. Note that you have to connect to HandsFree Profile, not to HandsFree Gateway.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean but can't code it. Do you have an example of this?

Comment: You can use Bluetooth Managr demo application from Bluetooth Framework (www.btframework.com) to query/enumerate target device services. Next you can use RfCommClient to connect to HFP control channel and send AT commands (change service UUID in the demo code cause by default it uses SPP).